# WebView crashes with signal 6 in Android 7.0 AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-7.0-nougat

Trying to construct a WebView object in an Android 7.0 AVD crashes the program with signal 6.

Trivial project, single activity. The code goes:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    }
}
```

That crashes every time. Tried several AVDs with different CPU architectures. Internally, the signal comes within native method `org.chromium.content.app.ContentMain.nativeStart()`. Any ideas, please? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: retargeting to API24 (Android 7.0) doesn't help.